# Activity Label and mulitask screen

Tags: java, android, xml

If I set the label attribute of an Activity that label is also used in the multitask screen

How can I keep the app name in the multitask screen and the custom label in the activity's action bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Activity's method `setTitle(String)` to set your custom title as follows:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setTitle("Custom Action Bar Title");
}
```

Good luck..